# Куки не передаются между страницами (JS)

Tags: javascript, cookie

Куки не передаются между страницами. Задаю при помощи JavaScript. Если написать то же самое в консоли браузера на странице, всё работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">
    console.log("js working");
    window.onload = function(){
        console.log("window.onload working");
        console.log('document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0]');
        console.log(document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0]);
        if(typeof(document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0])!="undefined"){
            dbOpts=document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0].getElementsByTagName("option");
            console.log('dbOpts');
            console.log(dbOpts);
            for(i=0;i<dbOpts.length;i++){
                console.log(dbOpts[i].getAttribute("selected")!=null);
                if (dbOpts[i].getAttribute("selected")!=null) dbselectedparam=dbOpts[i].getAttribute("value");
            }
            console.log(dbselectedparam);
            document.cookie = "dbselectedparam="+dbselectedparam+"; path=/";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Как это исправить?